# Second monitor via HDMI behavior is inconsistent?

Tags: display, resolution, user-interface

If I plug a secondary monitor via HDMI when I'm already logged in, everything runs smoothly.

But if I plug the HDMI while in the Welcome screen, and then I log in, the graphics in my main screen (laptop built in) get displayed in a huge scale.

Moreover, if I plug the HDMI cable while the computer is in suspend mode, and then I wake it up, after unlocking my session I only get graphics in the secondary (HDMI) screen.

If I let the computer go into suspend mode with the HDMI cable plugged, and then I unplug it, when I wake the computer up something wrong happens, but I can't really describe it. It's like the PC freezes, but not really. I can't remember well because I haven't replicated this lately. The other behaviors are pretty predictable.

I haven't tried what happens when plugging before booting, and I haven't tried with video-out options other than HDMI.

Is there a problem with my hardware? Or is elementary HDMI output buggy?

Using a G480 Lenovo laptop Quad-Core i3, Intel graphics, 1366 x 768 px
Secondary monitor is a Samsung 19", 1920 x 1080 px

Comment: This bug is reproducible for all ubuntu based distros. So it could be not related to Elementary OS.
I could reproduce same issue on: Ubuntu and Zorinos